# Wordpress warning: "private_to_published" Deprecated when creating nav with wp_update_nav_menu_item()

Tags: menus

For reasons specific to how my local development environment generates Wordpress menu items, I am trying to programmatically create a menu using **wp_create_nav_menu()** and **wp_update_nav_menu_item()**.

My code is as follows:

```
function register_dynamic_menu(){
    $menu_name = 'menuName';
    $menu_id = wp_create_nav_menu($menu_name);

    wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu_id, 0, array(
        'menu-item-title' =>  __('Logout'),
        'menu-item-classes' => 'logout',
        'menu-item-url' => wp_logout_url(),
        'menu-item-type' => 'custom',
        'menu-item-status' => 'publish')
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_dynamic_utility_addition' );
```

I am receiving the following Warning:

> Deprecated: private_to_published is deprecated since version 2.3.0! Use private_to_publish instead. in /var/www/html/web/wp/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5152

Can anyone provide insight into why this might be triggering the Depreciation warning?

Comment: Are you sure this comes from the code above?

Comment: I am pretty confidant it is. This message appears to be coming as a result of the 'menu-item-status' being 'publish' when this is changed to a different status this issue no longer occurs.